# webkit .appcache file caches dynamic page

Tags: iphone, android, google-app-engine, caching, mobile-website

The main page of my mobile web app is a .jsp page. My app requires login (Google App Engine), so there is a Log In button when the user is not logged in and a Log Out button when the user is logged in, all handled by code on the .jsp page.

I load a lot of JS code on the page, so I used a .appcache file to cache that. Unfortunatelly, even though I added my .jsp page to the Network area, the page is being cached in a funny way, ignoring the content server from the server. That means that my Log Out button shows when users are Logged Out and vice-versa.

I tried to add no-cache directives as meta tags, but they are all being ignored.

Ideas?

Comment: Don't set meta tags - send the correct headers in the first place!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to dive into HTML5, the page that references the manifest is automatically included in the manifest.

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/offline.html

> Q: Do I need to list my HTML pages in my cache manifest?
>
> A: Yes and no. If your entire web application is contained in a single page, just make sure that page points to the cache manifest using the manifest attribute. When you navigate to an HTML page with a manifest attribute, the page itself is assumed to be part of the web application, so you don’t need to list it in the manifest file itself. However, if your web application spans multiple pages, you should list all of the HTML pages in the manifest file, otherwise the browser would not know that there are other HTML pages that need to be downloaded and cached.

I have a similar issue, and I think I will end up loading the contents of the page via AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Caching in appCache is a two stage process: first the cache manifest is checked (in this case, as the page is loading), then if the content of it has changed, that content is reloaded. However, in your case, by that time, the stale page is already loaded and displayed.

The easiest fix would be to specifically exclude the page (but not the .js) from the appCache, so that only the js is cached, and not the page. I sounds like you might have figured that out, as you are trying to do it by putting the page in the network area. Check that that exclusion is correct, as that sounds like the problem, and that html cache attributes are being set correctly on that page.